# Pandas re-arranges DataFrame Columns?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Not asking how to re-arrange per se; rather noting that pandas is changing the order given:

[image]

Quite a surprise: it alphabetizes! Can you reject that and enforce your own order?

(python 2.7.11/anaconda/pandas 0.18.0/os 10.9.4)

Comment: It's using the dict keys which are inherently not in the order that they are created, you can do `df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'dist':xm, ''dem':ym}, columns = ['dist','dem'])` to enforce the order

Comment: This same question was asked only a few days ago I will find the dupe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible, because your input is a dictionary, the items in dictionary are not ordered. So I would just simply give:

```
my_order = ["dist", "dem"]
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({"dist":xm, "dem":ym}, columns=my_order)
```

Comment: I think I didn't run into this earlier because I was using a column list every  time for other reasons.  Thanks!